Is there a solution for using windows symbolic links with PHP?
I have created a symbolic directory link on my development server to allow my webserver to access photographs in my data folders to create galleries.
Server is Windows 10 (Version 10.0.19045.4291) running WAMPServer 3.2.3 with Apache 2.4.46.
I have been having problems accessing the folders and have stripped the code down to the bare minimum to eliminate other factors.  The code below works from the root of my webserver, but not from a subfolder. From the root I get a links with the folder names for each folder in the the symlink directory.  From the /galleries/ I get zero output from the server.
My first thought was that it's a relative path issue, but modifying the path, has achieved nothing.  I would have thought that /link/pictures/ would have taken it back to the webroot (www) to it should work from the webroot or any subdirectory, but no joy.  Adding or removing periods at the head of the string doesn't help either.
Any ideas what is going wrong here?
The symlink was created with:
mklink /D C:\Users\username\Documents\www\link\pictures C:\Users\username\Pictures\

The PHP code is as follows:
$gPath = "../link/pictures/galleries";
$allGalleries = glob("$gPath/*");  // read contents into an array
foreach ($allGalleries as $g) {
    $g = basename($g); // remove the path prepended by glob()
    echo "<p><a href='$gPath/$g'>$g</a></p>\n";
}


Check the result of realpath($gPath).

From the root, it returns the target path, c:\users\username\Pictures\Galleries.
From a subfolder it returns nothing.
I remain absolutely stumped.

Returning nothing means that the path does not exist or cannot be accessed. I think it's the former. .. represent the upper level folder, so for this code to work should be located in a folder at the same level as link. I'm not sure which folder you're referring to as a subfolder, but in general, this word is not meant to refer to a folder at that level.
